# Server-side paging but at the cost of losing sorting

Tags: javascript, rest, pagination

I have implemented server-side paging at 10 items per page for 1000 item result set, so that it pages 10 items per page. When I had it client side, I could page 10 at a time and if I sorted, it would sort against the entire 1000 items, but only show 10 items per page. However, using server-side paging where my REST call only returns 10 items at a time, my sorting is only within 1 page at a time since it can't compare against the other 990 items that are not called yet.

Given this, how is it possible to have server side paging and sorting across the entire total items? This assumes I am using REST/JSON presented using 
AngularJS.

What is interesting is that in my REST call using a tool like Postman, it properly maintains the overall order even with skips, but with the pagination calls in my Angular app, it only orders within the items (ex. 10).

Comment: If you're getting the items from a database, just sort in the query (`order by ...`).

Comment: If it's MySQL, you can use `LIMIT pagestart, pagesize` to return a set of rows starting from a particular place in the result set.

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue, I had another sort conflicting with the code. I am using orderby and it is working as planned once I removed the other sort that was left in older code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, where I had some extra code for sorting still on the page that was conflicting with the orderby within my REST call.